# View Contact counts against each Account using Map

Tags: map

I'm Newbie.

I like to get Contact counts against each Account Name using Map. I can get Contacts First Name related to Account Name but stuck to get Size of contacts.

Comment: Why don't you use rollup field for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check below code

```
 public map<Id,Integer> accountmap= new map<id,Integer>();.
```

In this line of code you will get account and related contacts . Better to filter it through using filter or apply limits otherwise you get all the account and it's related contact from your org.

```
List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id, name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) 
  FROM Account];//you can filter here or limit to avoid fetching too many rows 
for(Account acc : lstAccount)
  {
   accountmap.put(acc.Id,acc.contacts.size());
  }
 for(Account ac:lstAccount){
    if(accountmap.containskey(ac.id)){
   system.debug('account -->'+ac.Name+'contact size for each account-->'+accountmap.get(ac.id));
   }
}
```

In the account map constructs account and it's related contacts size.. in below for loop (account ac) using to check account and it's contact size
You can filter it based on your conditions in inner query

Comment: Thank you Sir..Annappa PH

Comment: I've downvoted this because it is a code dump. No explanation is given as to why this solves the issue at hand, so OP (and others) are unlikely to be able to learn how to avoid similar problems in the future.

Comment: I will provide the explanation..itsnot a code dump..I'll update soon..

Comment: I have typed in mobile..may be I'll make it proper structure later own wards